# Chrome or FF Equivalent to IE Debugger's Css Changes Summary?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, firefox-developer-tools

I just discovered this today:

[image]

I know Chrome has Persistant changes as an option (which is cool in it's own right) but not so nice when working across different servers.

Do Chrome or Firefox have anything like this or an add-on that does it perhaps?

Comment: This would probably be a better fit for [SuperUser](https://superuser.com).

Comment: You may want to remove the portion of your question which is asking for an add-on which does this. If you were just asking if it is done in the browser's DevTools, then it would be on-topic (software tools commonly used by programmers). Asking for us to find an add-on that does what you want is off-topic: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic** for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The History tab in Chrome DevTools will show you CSS changes you have made, with the ability to revert them. It's a very simple UI, and it doesn't work so well when you modify the existing stylesheets. If you add a new inspector stylesheet, and set or override styles, you will be able to see each modification as a separate entry in the History tab.

There are probably extensions out there that can do a better job, until the built-in one improves.

[image: CSS changes]

Answer (score 1):

The Firefox DevTools (as of Firefox 51.0.1) show you with a little green stripe besides the style that it got changed, but they don't have a separate panel to list all changes.

[image: Changed styles in Firefox DevTools *Rules* side panel]